# Google App Scrip to move Google Sheet Column based on "question text"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for some assistance if possible on a script to automatically process and sort **rows** in a Google Sheets to another set of sheets within contained within the main. I'm fairly new to JS so please bear with me!

Example:

I have an app set up to populate a Google sheet with data based on survey responses captured outside of Google.

Column A=1 is the user email, Column B=2 contains a variety of questions, Column C=3 contains the users responses.

Each user is asked 6 questions in the form of a short survey. This automatically populates into the sheet from the source database with no issue.

Where I am spinning gears is taking the specific question from each response (row) and moving row within its own sheet.

````
function CopyDataToNewFile() {


    // How Many Columns over to copy
    var columsCopyCount = 6;

    // A=1 B=2 C=3 D=4 E=5

    // What Column(s) to Monitor
    var columnsToMonitor = 2;

    // B=2 Monitors Question text

    //TARGET SPREAD SHEETS
    var questionText1 = "<p>Did you enjoy this course?</p>";
    var questionText2 = "<p>How long have you been using the system?</p>";
    var questionText3 = "<p>Which alternatives did you consider before purchasing the product?</p>";
    var questionText4 = "<p>Thinking about your course, which module did you consider the most valuable to you?</p>";
    var questionText5 = "<p>On a scale of 1 to 5, how satisfied are you with your course experience today?</p>";
    var questionText6 = "<p>How can we improve your experience</p>";

    //SOURCE SPREAD SHEET
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID REMOVED');
    var sourceSpreadSheetSheetID = ss.getSheetByName("Main Sheet");
    var sourceSpreadSheetSheetID1 = ss.getSheetByName(questionText1);
    var sourceSpreadSheetSheetID2 = ss.getSheetByName(questionText2);
    var sourceSpreadSheetSheetID3 = ss.getSheetByName(questionText3);
    var sourceSpreadSheetSheetID4 = ss.getSheetByName(questionText4);
    var sourceSpreadSheetSheetID5 = ss.getSheetByName(questionText5);
    var sourceSpreadSheetSheetID6 = ss.getSheetByName(questionText6);

    var data = sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.getRange(2, 1, sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.getLastRow() - 1, sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.getLastColumn()).getValues();

    var questionText1 = [];
    var questionText2 = [];
    var questionText3 = [];
    var questionText4 = [];
    var questionText5 = [];
    var questionText6 = [];


    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        var rValue = data[i][6];

        if (rValue == questionText1) {
            questionText1.push(data[i]);
        } else if (rValue == questionText2) {
            questionText2.push(data[i]);
        } else if (rValue == questionText3) {
            questionText3.push(data[i]);
        } else if (rValue == questionText4) {
            questionText4.push(data[i]);
        } else if (rValue == questionText5) {
            questionText5.push(data[i]);
        } else if (rValue == questionText6) {
            questionText6.push(data[i]);
        } else { // Fail Safe
            questionText5.push(data[i]);
        }


    }

    if (questionText1.length > 0) {
        sourceSpreadSheetSheetID1.getRange(sourceSpreadSheetSheetID1.getLastRow() + 1, 1, questionText1.length, questionText1[0].length).setValues(questionText1);
    }

    if (questionText2.length > 0) {
        sourceSpreadSheetSheetID2.getRange(sourceSpreadSheetSheetID2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, questionText2.length, questionText2[0].length).setValues(questionText2);
    }

    if (questionText3.length > 0) {
        sourceSpreadSheetSheetID3.getRange(sourceSpreadSheetSheetID3.getLastRow() + 1, 1, questionText3.length, questionText3[0].length).setValues(questionText3);
    }

    if (questionText4.length > 0) {
        sourceSpreadSheetSheetID4.getRange(sourceSpreadSheetSheetID4.getLastRow() + 1, 1, questionText4.length, questionText4[0].length).setValues(questionText4);
    }

    if (questionText5.length > 0) {
        sourceSpreadSheetSheetID5.getRange(sourceSpreadSheetSheetID5.getLastRow() + 1, 1, questionText5.length, questionText5[0].length).setValues(questionText5);
    }

    if (questionText6.length > 0) {
        sourceSpreadSheetSheetID6.getRange(sourceSpreadSheetSheetID6.getLastRow() + 1, 1, questionText6.length, questionText6[0].length).setValues(questionText6);
    }

    // Will delete the rows of Main Sheet once the data is copided to other sheets
    sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.deleteRows(2, sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.getLastRow() - 1);


    // Optional Fail Safe

}else {
    var targetRange = sourceSpreadSheetSheetID1.getRange(sourceSpreadSheetSheetID1.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.getRange(i, 1, 1, columsCopyCount).copyTo(targetRange), { contentsOnly: true };
    //sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.deleteRow(i);
} ```

The source example I worked from can be found here! 
[stackoverflow thread][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932943/google-app-script-google-spreadsheets-move-row-based-on-cell-value-efficiently

When ran in Google scripts I get the following error: 

>
Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
CopyDataToNewFile
@ 

I have tried changing around around the string on the **rValue** as I'm sure this is the culprit (I may be wrong) as I think I should be referencing the text "<p>Did you enjoy this course?</p>";? 

        if (rValue == questionText1) {
            questionText1.push(data[i]);
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
const BASE_COLUMN = 2; // Column with sheet name for distribution

function distribute() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Input");
  while(sheet.getLastRow()>1) {
    var row = sheet.getRange("A2:F2").getValues()[0];

    var outputSheetName = row[BASE_COLUMN-1];  // Column 2 is distribution column
    if(outputSheetName != '' ) {
      var outputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(outputSheetName); // Get destination sheet
      outputSheet = outputSheet || SpreadsheetApp.getActive().insertSheet(outputSheetName); // Create if not exists

      outputSheet.appendRow(row); // copy row

    }
    sheet.deleteRow(2); // remove original row
  }
}
```

Example
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vY9FZ4PBCxtI3pmsjYtDqtec_n-EQy-H7j3PS_8EBU4/edit#gid=353094948

Script is embed in sheet.

It takes rows and distributes them among different sheets.
Row for sheet name is **BASE_COLUMN** (2 in my example)

Comment: Thanks for the help Roma, this helped solve the issue :)